# Trees: how can I prove that if two vertices share the same descendant, then one of them must be the descendant of the other?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Question from my book:

> Show that if two distinct vertices in a rooted tree, u and v, have a common descendant, then vertex u is a descendant of v or vertex v is a descendant of u. You can assume that every vertex in a rooted tree has a unique path to the root.

Intuitively and graphically, this makes sense. I have no clue how to prove this rigorously, though. I got this far:

- suppose $y$ is a descendant of $u$
- suppose $y$ is also a descendant of $v$
- then $u$ must be an ancestor of $y$, and $v$ must also be an ancestor of $y$

I'm missing the final link. How can I claim that $u$ is an ancestor of $v$ or vice versa? I'm thinking I have to use paths, but it's not too clear how I can do that. Here's what I was thinking for that as well:

- arbitrary path from root $r$ to $y$ must pass through $u$ and $v$: $<r, *, *, *, u, *, *, v, *, y>$

That's all I got :/

Comment: I would probably do it by contradiction.  Suppose neither is a descendant of the other.  Then show that their common descendant has two distinct paths back to the root.

Comment: @tilper Thanks--why would their common descendant have to have two distinct paths to the root?

Comment: Let $w$ be the common descendant of $u$ and $v$.  Since $w$ is a descendant of $u$, there is a path from $w$ to $u$.  Since $u$ is a descendant of the root, call it $r$, then there is a path from $u$ to $r$.  Thus there is a path from $w$ to $r$ and it goes through $u$.  A similar argument shows there is a path from $w$ to $v$ and from $v$ to $r$, and thus a path from $w$ to $r$ through $v$.  Use this setup, combined with the facts that (1) $u \ne v$, and (2) neither $u$ nor $v$ is a descendant of the other, to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $v_1,v_2$ are two vertices with the common descendant $u$, and $r$ is the root. Lets denote by $P_x$ the unique path from $x$ to $r$. Note that $x$ being a descedant of $y$ means exactly that $y\in P_x$.

Because $v_1$ and $v_2$ are both ancestors of $u$, we have $v_1,v_2\in P_u$. Going along $P_u$ from $u$ to $r$, we encounter one of the vertices $v_i$ first, w.l.o.g. say it is $v_1$. Then the subpath $v_1P_ur\subseteq P_u$ is a path from $v_1$ to $r$ (hence the unique one) containing $v_2$. Thus, $v_2\in P_{v_1}$ and therefore $v_1$ is a descedant of $v_2$. Equivalently for the case when $v_2$ is encountered first. $\quad\square$

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!

Comment: Can I argue that if v1 is not a descendant of v2, then I can find 2 distinct paths from u to r, such that$ v_1\in P1_{u} $and $v_2\in P2_{u}$ . Hence we end up with a cycle in the tree.. hence a contradiction